# Click: Is it possible to pass multiple inputs to CliRunner.invoke?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-interface, python-click

I have a click command called `download` which prompts the user for a username and password before downloading a series of files:

```
$ python download.py
Username: jkarimi91
Password: 1234
Download complete!
```

To test this command, I need to be able to pass both a `username` and a `password`, separately, to `stdin`. The `CliRunner.invoke()` method has an `input` argument but it does not accept lists. Is it possible to pass multiple inputs to `CliRunner.invoke()`?

Comment: @StephenRauch, an `input` argument, not an `input` method. See [Input Streams](http://click.pocoo.org/5/testing/#input-streams) in click documentation.

Comment: My mistake, i made a typo but have since corrected it; input is an argument for the invoke method of clirunner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass multiple inputs by passing string joined by newline (`\n`):

```
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner


def test_prompts():
    @click.command()
    @click.option('--username', prompt=True)
    @click.option('--password', prompt=True)
    def test(username, password):
        # download ..
        click.echo('Download complete!')

    # OR
    #
    # @click.command()
    # def test():
    #     username = click.prompt('Username')
    #     password = click.prompt('Password', hide_input=True)
    #     # download ..
    #     click.echo('Download complete!')


    runner = CliRunner()
    result = runner.invoke(test, input='username\npassword\n') # <---
    assert not result.exception
    assert result.output.endswith('Download complete!\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_prompts()
```

Comment: would it be possible if we didn't add `username` and `password` as arguments but retrieved them inside of `test()` using `raw_input()` and `getpass.getpass()` instead?

Comment: @jkarimi, If you use `click.prompt()`, it's possible. I didn't test with `raw_input()` or `getpass.getpass()`.

Comment: @jkarimi, I tested with `raw_input`, `getpass.getpass`. It works with `raw_input`, but not with `getpass.getpass`.  You'd better to use `click.prompt('Username')` and `click.prompt('Password', hide_input=True)` for password input which works very well with `runner.invoke(..., input=..)`